# date send error in location.href in jsp

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp

first i ran intro_do.jsp using form action in intro.jsp including value 'ID','password'. and where in intro_do.jsp, compare value in database using while&if like that.

```
case 2 :
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);                    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();                  while (rs.next()) {
                    if (stid.equals(rs.getString("Student ID"))) {
                        if (password.equals(rs.getString("password"))) {
                            String myname = rs.getString("name");
                            %>
                            <script>
                                alert('login success');
                                //location.href="student.jsp?param="+;
                                location.href = "student.jsp+param=" + <%=myname%>;
                                //location.href = "student.jsp";
                                </script>
                            <%
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                %><script>
                    alert('fail');
                    location.href = "intro.jsp";
                </script>
                <%
                break;
```

i dont know why this fail?!

Comment: You should read first [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

it's  not good practice to combine java code and script. use ajax or form submission to the servlet. OR set the value in any of the fields of form. retrieve it in js and do the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Of corse, you obviously should specify **which error** you have found when executing your example. Anyway, I'd dare to guess that the error arises in the javascript scriptlet: You've mistaken the scripting scope of the `myname` variable. It should go like this:

```
location.href = "student.jsp?param=<%=myname%>";
```

... because the JSP variables are resolved in the first place in the server side, so the HTML page delivered to the browser will be like this:

```
location.href = "student.jsp?param=joe";
```

Another important detail in this line is that `myname` is assumed not to contain blank characters. Or else, you should escape it first:

```
location.href = "student.jsp?param=<%=URLEncoder.encode(myname,"UTF-8")%>";
```